# Prove that if $f$ is continuous in $[0,1]$, and $f(0)=f(1)= \frac{1}{3}$, then there is $c \in (0,1)$ so that $f(c)=c^2$

Tags: calculus

Prove that if $f$ is continuous in $[0,1]$, and $f(0)=f(1)= \frac{1}{3}$, then there is $c \in (0,1)$ so that $f(c)=c^2$

Stuck here. Any assistance will be appreciated!

Also, please help me with hints only, don't want to be spoon-fed.

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $h$ the function defined by $h(x)=f(x)-x^2$ then $h$ is continuous and

$$h(0)h(1)<0$$
hence by the intermediate value theorem the result follows.

Comment: So $h(0)=\frac{1}{3}-0=\frac{1}{3}$, and $h(1)=\frac{1}{3}-1=-\frac{2}{3}$. So by the intermediate value theorem there is $c \in (0,1)$ so that $h(c)=0 \rightarrow 0=f(c)-c^2 \rightarrow f(c)=c^2$. Thank you! And yes, wasn't very hinting... but still thanks...

Comment: You're welcome @Reyo